# Solve $a^x+b^x=c$ for $x$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, exponentiation, closed-form, real-numbers

I need to solve an equation of the form 
$$a^x+b^x=c$$
with $a,b\in (0,1)$ and $c\in(0,2)$ (and I'm solving for $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$).

I know this admits a solution (details below), but it's such a simple equation that I'm sure its properties have been studied before and I need to find that literature. And if this admits a closed form solution, then my summer would be saved! :)

**Existence:** Since $a,b\in (0,1)$, the left side is continuous strictly decreasing in $x$ for all positive values. Moreover, $a^0+b^0\equiv 2>c$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} a^x+b^x \equiv 0<c$ for all admissible parameter values. By the intermediate value theorem, $x>0$ must exist. But what is it???

Comment: if we take $y=a^x$ than equation will become $y+b^{log_b(a)}$

Comment: If I were you, I would have tried a few values of $a$ and $b$ and seeing if there was any discernible pattern. :-)

Comment: This may be wrong and rather stupid of me, but why not take logarithms, use the law $\ln a^x=x\ln a$, and divide by $\ln a+\ln b$?

Comment: @GeorgeSimpson $\ln (a^x + b^x) \neq \ln a^x + \ln b^x$.

Comment: Please let me know when you find a closed form.

Comment: NO CLOSED FORM. MOST OF MATHEMATICS FAILS TO HAVE ANY CLOSED FORM.

Comment: @Boris After substitution, the equation becomes $y+b^{\log_a(y)}=y+a^{\log_a(y)\log_a(b)}=y+y^{\log_a(b)}=c$ and not  $y+b^{\log_b(a)}=y+a$. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @WillJagy At the same time, a lot of pretty little equations like this have names that they go by, and knowing that would also make me happy. :)

Comment: @ZainPatel Thanks for the suggestion... I've done that but what I really need to do is plug in the solution into another equation and well – the implicit functions just get really huge and cumbersome.

Comment: See what you mean, names. Forever more, this one will be called Michele's Equation!!!

Comment: @WillJagy No shouting in the forum please.

Comment: Related question, posted the same day: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371193/solve-for-x-ax-b-x-c-how-to-approach-this-kind-of-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most general case, the root of equation $$f(x)=a^x+b^x-c$$ does not show any closed form and numerical methods should be used.

The root is bounded by the roots of $2a^x=c$ and $2b^x=c$ which are simple and then we have a range which contains the solution we look for.

So, a root finder method, such as Newton method could start,a the mid point, using $$x_0=\frac{ \log (\sqrt{ab})}{ \log (a) \log (b)}\log \left(\frac{c}{2}\right)$$ and will converge quite fast taking into account the acceptable ranges $a,b\in (0,1)$, $c\in(0,2)$.

For illustration purposes, consider $a=\frac{1}{3}$, $b=\frac{1}{2}$, $c=1$. So, the successive iterates will be $$x_0=1.15391338000$$ $$x_1=1.12311432825$$ $$x_2=1.12353135181$$ $$x_3=1.12353142978$$ which is the soution for twelve significant figures.